# Remove a white background - sharp library

Tags: node.js, sharp

Is it possible to replace a white background of an image with transparency using the sharp library?

Comment: Please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)... what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unflatten` command assuming you meet the following requirements:

> Ensure the image has an alpha channel with all white pixel values made fully transparent. Existing alpha channel values for non-white pixels remain unchanged. This feature is experimental and the API may change.

[sharp docs related to unflatten](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-operation#unflatten)

for example:

```
await sharp("my_image.png").unflatten().toFile("my_image_transparent.png");
```